# AJAX - return JS Array and use it in success event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

Hello I am having a strange problem. I am making an AJAX call to get an array of objects and the request returns:

```
[{
                        title: 'xxx xxx xx ',
                        start: '2015-11-23',     
                        end: '2015-11-24',
                        color: '#99a5a8',
                        customer_name: 'xxx xxx',
                        priority: 0,
                        half_day_dates: ['1968-01-01']
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'xxxx xx xxx ',
                        start: '2015-11-23',     
                        end: '2015-11-24',
                        color: '#99a5a8',
                        customer_name: 'xxx',
                        priority: 0,
                        half_day_dates: ['1968-01-01']
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'xxx xxx xxx ',
                        start: '2015-11-23',     
                        end: '2015-11-24',
                        color: '#99a5a8',
                        customer_name: 'xxx',
                        priority: 1,
                        half_day_dates: ['1968-01-01']
                    }];
```

My AJAX call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax/calendar_ajax.php',
        data: events_to_render,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {      

            console.log(data);
        }
    }).fail(function() {

    });
```

So the problem is JS considers the return result to be HTML of some sort, as `console.log(data)` outputs it as text rather than a JS array, so I can't iterate through the array of objects. Any ideas? (I am sure I am missing something simple).

**ANSWER:**

Thank you everyone for helping me out, in the end the solution was really simple:

All I had to do is `eval(data)` and it transformed my text into a proper JS object array.

Comment: update your question to include `calendar_ajax.php`

Comment: This isn't valid JSON notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for helping me out, in the end the solution was really simple:

All I had to do is `eval(data)` and it transformed my text into a proper JS object array.

Answer (score 3):

[See `JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
success: function(data){
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(json[0]["start"]); //will output '2015-11-23'
}
```

Comment: No, because OP is already setting `dataType: "json"` and anyway, if server returns json: `If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object...`  EDIT: but OP isn't returning valid JSON, so maybe... I'm not sure hoiw this would be handled

Comment: If I do JSON.parse(data) I get unexpected token t error.

All i am trying to do is use the text returned as part of the js script. so I can do something like ` var events = data`

Comment: @uFlock Try removing `dataType` option, then try using `var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));`. Or better, returns valid JSON from server... (keeping in this case `dataType` and not parsing it in success

Comment: @A.Wolff If I try `var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));` then I get right back where I am started. what do you mean by valid json?

Comment: @uFlock `what do you mean by valid json?` JSON is a notation object with really strict rules. You aren't following them here. Your JS object isn't a JSON valid notation ones. This is valid one: http://jsfiddle.net/2b2aL9d7/1/

Comment: it works here ( jsfiddle.net/2b2aL9d7) because you are not fetching the data via ajax request, if I just take the output and manually paste it in the script it works. is it possible to return js script from ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Add the json header  `header('Content-Type: application/json');` to your ajaxed php & echo the json encoded data `echo json_encode(array('data' => $data));`